# problem with proper filtering of parameters in querydsl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, querydsl

I have a problem with querydsl. I have a method created that is supposed to filter by various parameters such as.
type of figure

- area from, area to
- circumference from, circumference to
- creation date from, to
- who created,
- by figure parameters, from - to
  The method does not work for area, perimeter and parameters. If the given parameter does not match any object it returns an empty json, but once it wants to filter it returns all objects from the database. I don't know what the problem could be. Someone can help me?

CODE:

```
@Entity 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) 
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING) 
@Table(name = "shapes") 
@QueryEntity 
public class Shape implements Serializable{ 
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
private long id; 
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false) 
private String type; 
@Version private int version; 
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") 
private User createdBy; 
private LocalDateTime createdAt; 
private LocalDateTime lastModifiedAt; 
private String lastModifiedBy; }
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SQUARE")
public class Square extends Shape {

    private double height;

    private double area;

    private double perimeter;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void calculateAreaAndPerimeter() {
        area = height * height;
        perimeter = 4 * height;
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class ShapeManagementService implements IShapeManagementService {

    private final ShapeRepository shapeRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final List<IShapeService> shapeServices;
    private final JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShapeManagementService.class);

    public ShapeManagementService(ShapeRepository shapeRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository, List<IShapeService> shapeServices, JPAQueryFactory queryFactory) {
        this.shapeRepository = shapeRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.shapeServices = shapeServices;
        this.queryFactory = queryFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public ShapeDto saveShape(ShapeRequestDto shapeRequestDto, String username) {
        IShapeService shapeService = shapeServices.stream()
                .filter(h -> h.getShape().equalsIgnoreCase(shapeRequestDto.getType()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow();
        return shapeService.save(shapeRequestDto, username);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ShapeDto> getFilteredShapes(String createdBy, String type, Double areaFrom, Double areaTo,
                                            Double perimeterFrom, Double perimeterTo, LocalDateTime createdAtFrom,
                                            LocalDateTime createdAtTo, Double heightFrom, Double heightTo) {
        QShape shape = QShape.shape;
        QSquare square = QSquare.square;
        QCircle circle = QCircle.circle;

        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();

        if (createdBy != null) {
            predicate.and(shape.createdBy.username.eq(createdBy));
        }

        if (type != null) {
            predicate.and(shape.type.eq(type));
        }

        if (areaFrom != null || areaTo != null || perimeterFrom != null || perimeterTo != null) {
            predicate.and(shape.instanceOf(Square.class));
        }

        if (areaFrom != null) {
            predicate.and(square.area.goe(areaFrom));
        }

        if (areaTo != null) {
            predicate.and(square.area.loe(areaTo));
        }

        if (perimeterFrom != null) {
            predicate.and(square.perimeter.goe(perimeterFrom));
        }

        if (perimeterTo != null) {
            predicate.and(square.perimeter.loe(perimeterTo));
        }

        if (heightFrom != null || heightTo != null) {
            predicate.andAnyOf(square.height.between(heightFrom, heightTo), circle.radius.between(heightFrom, heightTo));
        }

        if (createdAtFrom != null) {
            predicate.and(shape.createdAt.goe(createdAtFrom));
        }

        if (createdAtTo != null) {
            predicate.and(shape.createdAt.loe(createdAtTo));
        }

        JPAQuery<Shape> query = queryFactory.selectFrom(shape)
                .leftJoin(square).on(shape.instanceOf(Square.class))
                .leftJoin(circle).on(shape.instanceOf(Circle.class))
                .where(predicate)
                .groupBy(shape.id); // Grupowanie wyników po id figury

        List<Shape> shapes = query.fetch();

        return shapes.stream()
                .map(this::convertToDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    public ShapeDto convertToDto(Shape shape) {
        ShapeDto shapeDto;
        if (shape instanceof Square) {
            shapeDto = convertSquareToDto((Square) shape);
//        } else if (shape instanceof Circle) {
//            shapeDto = convertCircleToDto((Circle) shape);
        } else {
            shapeDto = new ShapeDto();
        }

        shapeDto.setId(shape.getId());
        shapeDto.setType(shape.getType());
        shapeDto.setCreatedBy(shape.getCreatedBy().getUsername());
        shapeDto.setCreatedAt(shape.getCreatedAt());
        shapeDto.setLastModifiedAt(shape.getLastModifiedAt());
        shapeDto.setLastModifiedBy(shape.getLastModifiedBy());

        return shapeDto;
    }

    private SquareDto convertSquareToDto(Square square) {
        SquareDto squareDto = new SquareDto();
        squareDto.setHeight(square.getHeight());
        squareDto.setPerimeter(square.getPerimeter());
        squareDto.setArea(square.getArea());
        return squareDto;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class SquareService implements IShapeService {

    private final SquareRepository squareRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private final SquareFactory squareFactory;
    private final ShapeRepository shapeRepository;

    public SquareService(SquareRepository squareRepository, UserRepository userRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper, SquareFactory squareFactory, ShapeRepository shapeRepository) {
        this.squareRepository = squareRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
        this.squareFactory = squareFactory;
        this.shapeRepository = shapeRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public ShapeDto save(ShapeRequestDto shapeRequestDto, String username) {
        Square square = squareFactory.createSquare(shapeRequestDto, username);
        Square squareToSave = squareRepository.save(square);
        SquareDto squareDto = modelMapper.map(squareToSave, SquareDto.class);
        squareDto.getCreatedBy();
        squareDto.setCreatedBy(square.getCreatedBy().getUsername());
        squareDto.setArea(square.getArea());
        squareDto.setPerimeter(square.getPerimeter());
        return squareDto;
    }

    @Override
    public String getShape() {
        return "SQUARE";
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/shapes")
public class ShapeController {

    private final IShapeManagementService shapeManagementService;

    public ShapeController(IShapeManagementService shapeManagementService) {
        this.shapeManagementService = shapeManagementService;
    }
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_CREATOR')")
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ShapeDto> addShape(@RequestBody ShapeRequestDto shapeRequestDto, Principal p) {
        ShapeDto shapeDto = shapeManagementService.saveShape(shapeRequestDto, p.getName());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(shapeDto);

    }
    @GetMapping(value = "/parameters")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ShapeDto>> getShapes(@RequestParam(required = false) String createdBy,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) String type,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) Double areaFrom,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) Double areaTo,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) Double perimeterFrom,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) Double perimeterTo,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime createdAtFrom,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime createdAtTo,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) Double heightFrom,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) Double heightTo) {
        List<ShapeDto> filteredShapes = shapeManagementService.getFilteredShapes(
                createdBy, type, areaFrom, areaTo, perimeterFrom, perimeterTo, createdAtFrom, createdAtTo, heightFrom, heightTo);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(filteredShapes);
    }
}




I tried searching all over the internet.
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).